# how to keep a lot of arrays in one variable python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a lot of arrays, every is 2D, but has other sizes. I am looking for any good idea how to keep them in one variable. Order of them is important. What do you recommend? Arrays? Dictionaries? Any ideas?

My problem:
I have numpy array:

```
b=np.array([])
```

And now I want to add to them e.g. array:

```
a=np.array([0,1,2])
```

And later:

```
c=np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
```

Etc

Result should be:

```
b=([0,1,2], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
```

I don't know how to get it in numpy and without initializing size of first array.

Comment: What's wrong with a list?

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering is important, store them in a list (`mylist = [array1, array2, ...]`) - or, if you're not going to need to change or shuffle them around after creating the list, store them in a tuple (`mylist = (array1, array2, ...)`).

Both of these structures can store arbitrary object types (they don't care that your arrays are different sizes, or even that they are all the same kind of object at all) and both maintain a consistent ordering which can be accessed through `mylist[0]`, `mylist[1]` etc. They will also appear in the correct order when you go through them using `for an_array in mylist:` etc.

Comment: Ok, but I'm using numpy array. And when I'm using insert, append or concatenate I'm not getting effort I want...

Comment: Why are you trying to use a numpy array for your enclosing data structure, instead of storing your arrays in something more appropriate like a list? That's not what they're designed to do, so you'll naturally run into a lot of problems with this approach.